# navigation bar style change while iphone theme is in dark mode

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios-darkmode

Hello I am creating app with `Swift` i have just started creating app and take one `View Controller` and `embed in` navigation controller and for remove navigation bar border i used below code

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for:.default)            
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
```

and for dealing with Dark Theme i have added one more line as below

i am adding Screen Shot Of Light Mode And Dark Mode for better explanation

```
overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

but when iphone is in darkmode Navigation Bar Style changed to light is there any solution to handle navigation bar style while dark mode is enabled

[This dark mode Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p11Bg.png)

[This Is Light Mode Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIR3f.png)

Kindly tell me if anyone have any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Use `UINavigationBarAppearance()` to customize `UINavigationBar` in iOS13 (where dark mode feature appeared):

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
   let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
   appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorYouNeed
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
}
```